# response is undefined using Axios and Express

Tags: node.js, express, axios, undefined, response

I have this simple post method in back-end:

```
router.post('/users', async function(request, response) {
  try {
    const userToRegister = request.body;
    const user = await CreateUserService.execute(userToRegister);
  
    return response.json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return response.status(401).json({ message: 'email already registered' });
  }
});
```

At the front end i'm trying to catch the response if the users is already registered, like this:

```
api.post('users', user.userFields)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
```

In this case, response is always `undefined`.

If a pass `return response.json(err);` in backend it works fine.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Did you try to look at `user` at the line `return response.json(user);` by setting a breakpoint?

Comment: What is `api.post()` in the client?  Is that axios?  And, why isn't the request URL `/users`?

Comment: @Anatoly when debugging the line `return response.json(user)`, the debug pointer didn't entered in the try block, it was directly to the catch block.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, is Axios. I guess the first '/' doesn't matters is this case. Tried with `api.post('/users')` and got no sucess.

Comment: Did you do `console.log(user)` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(user))` right before the `return response.json(user);` to see exactly what you have and to make sure you're code is getting there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind guys, found error.

My fail was in the `user` catch block of `CreateUserService`.